# Como eliminar Propiedad de Objeto sin saber su Key. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, objeto

En esta oportunidad tengo una duda, tengo este objeto de ejemplo:

```
"pasada" : {
    "09-10" : 34.11,
    "09-11" : 35.73,
    "09-12" : 34.03,
    "09-13" : 35.85,
    "09-14" : 38.75,
    "09-15" : 34.07,
    "09-16" : 32.46,
    "09-17" : 34.57
}
```

El cual sus `key: valor` siempre van a cambiar y no podría saber cual es `key` como podría hacer para borrar el ultimo elemento en este caso `"09-17"` o el primero que seria `"09-10"` dependiendo de mi requerimiento.

Agradezco la ayuda que puedan prestarme!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener las *keys* de tu objeto y luego eliminarlas según el *index* que desees, por ejemplo la primer key (index : 0), la tercera (index : 2), etc.

```js
var pasada = {
             "09-10" : 34.11,
             "09-11" : 35.73,
             "09-12" : 34.03,
             "09-13" : 35.85,
             "09-14" : 38.75,
             "09-15" : 34.07,
             "09-16" : 32.46,
             "09-17" : 34.57
              };
              
var keys = Object.keys(pasada);
var indexKeyToDelete = 0;

console.log("El objeto con todas las keys:");
console.log(pasada);

// Equivale a "delete pasada.NombreDeLaKey" o "delete pasada["NombreDeLaKey"]"
delete pasada[keys[indexKeyToDelete]];

console.log("El objeto con la key borrada:");
console.log(pasada);
```

### Información adicional:

> `Object.keys` devuelve un array cuyos elementos son *strings*
>   correspondientes a las propiedades enumerables que se encuentran
>   directamente en el objeto.
>
> El operador `delete`  elimina una propiedad de un objeto.

Comment: Es importante hacer notar que el orden de las llaves/claves es un poco impredecible, aunque suele ser el orden de creación. Quizá necesites hacer uso de llaves.sort(...) para ordenalas si tienes un criterio claro (orden alfabético, por ejemplo)

Comment: estupendo, funcionado a la perfección y adaptado a mi necesidad, me gusta mucho mas que puedo controlar el numero de la key a eliminar, gracias!

Answer (score 5):

Puedes obtener las key asi:

`var llaves = Object.keys(pasada);`

Como resultado te daria un arreglo:

`[09-10, 09-11, ... ]`

Ahora que tienes las llaves puedes jugar a lo que quieras

```
var llave = llaves[0]; // Es la primera

var llave = llaves[llaves.length - 1]; // es la ultima
```

Y puedes ocupar este arreglo para hacer un número indeterminado de combinaciones.

- Obtener las pares o nones
- Obtener las que empiecen on 9
- etc.

Ahora que conoces la llave solo borrala

```
delete pasada[llave];
```